# JQuery : show "loading" after a certain delay

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

How can I once clicked on my button with the class : *load-more-reviews*, add a 3 seconds delay written "Loading..." then show the data?

Here is my Ajax :

```
// Loading button

$('button.load-more-reviews').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var _this = $(this);
var product_id = _this.data('product-id');
var limit = _this.data('limit');
var _btn_text = _this.html();
_this.html('Loading...');
_this.attr('disabled', true);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'actions/ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: 'fetch_reviews',
        product_id: product_id,
        limitcount: limit
    },
   dataType: 'json',
    success: function(r) {
        _this.html(_btn_text);
        _this.attr('disabled', false);
        console.log(r);
        _this.data('limit', r['limit']);
        if (r['status'] == '1') {
            $('div.reviews-block').append(r['html']);
        } else if (r['status'] == '2') {
            _this.hide();
        }
        return false
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are looking for [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `beforeSend` event to show the "loading" text before sending the request, and `window.setTimeout` function with 3000 delay to replace it by the result in 3 seconds.

```js
    beforeSend: function() { 
       _this.html('Loading...');
       _this.attr('disabled', true);
    },
    success: function(r) {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
          _this.html(_btn_text);
          _this.attr('disabled', false);
          console.log(r);
          _this.data('limit', r['limit']);
          if (r['status'] == '1') {
              $('div.reviews-block').append(r['html']);
          } else if (r['status'] == '2') {
              _this.hide();
          }
          return false
      }, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: Omg this is wonderful !
I didn't know I could show the event loading with beforeSend.

Thank you !

Comment: @Finalmix6, there's also the _complete_ event. You can use it to do whatever you want to do **after** the _success_ event.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just show the message before the AJAX call is made. Once it has been completed (it has reached the success function), you should then fade it out.

However, if you want a 3 second delay regardless, you can do something similar to the example I've provided below.

```js
$('#loading-message').fadeIn();

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loading-message').fadeOut();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="loading-message" style="display: none;">Loading...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simply added a timeout around the whole code inside of the button click function. This shows a loading div, which will hide after 3 seconds

Try this

```
<div class="loading" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>

$('button.load-more-reviews').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    var product_id = _this.data('product-id');
    var limit = _this.data('limit');
    var _btn_text = _this.html();
    _this.html('Loading...');
    _this.attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'actions/ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'fetch_reviews',
            product_id: product_id,
            limitcount: limit
        },
       dataType: 'json',
        success: function(r) {
            _this.html(_btn_text);
            _this.attr('disabled', false);
            console.log(r);
            _this.data('limit', r['limit']);
           if (r['status'] == '1') {
                $('div.reviews-block').append(r['html']);
            } else if (r['status'] == '2') {
                _this.hide();
            }
            return false
        }
    });
    }, 3000);

    $('.loading').fadeOut('500');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try something like this :

The text Loading in the button is only showed when ajax is loading

```js
$('button.load-more-reviews').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var _this = $(this);
  var product_id = _this.data('product-id');
  var limit = _this.data('limit');
  var _btn_text = _this.html();
  _this.html('Loading...');
  _this.attr('disabled', true);
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'actions/ajax.php',
      data: {
          action: 'fetch_reviews',
          product_id: product_id,
          limitcount: limit
      },
     dataType: 'json',
      success: function(r) {
          _this.html(_btn_text);
          _this.attr('disabled', false);
          console.log(r);
          _this.data('limit', r['limit']);
          if (r['status'] == '1') {
              $('div.reviews-block').append(r['html']);
              _this.html('TEST');
              _this.attr('disabled', false);
          } else if (r['status'] == '2') {
              _this.hide();
          }
          return false
      },
      error: function(){
        _this.html('TEST');
        _this.attr('disabled', false);
      }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='load-more-reviews'>TEST</button>
```

If you want make something more slow if ajax is too speed for you, you can make a `setTimeout` like this :

```js
$('button.load-more-reviews').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var _this = $(this);
  var product_id = _this.data('product-id');
  var limit = _this.data('limit');
  var _btn_text = _this.html();
  _this.html('Loading...');
  _this.attr('disabled', true);
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'actions/ajax.php',
      data: {
          action: 'fetch_reviews',
          product_id: product_id,
          limitcount: limit
      },
     dataType: 'json',
      success: function(r) {
          _this.html(_btn_text);
          _this.attr('disabled', false);
          console.log(r);
          _this.data('limit', r['limit']);
          if (r['status'] == '1') {
              $('div.reviews-block').append(r['html']);
              setTimeout(function(){
                  _this.html('TEST');
                  _this.attr('disabled', false);
              }, 3000);
          } else if (r['status'] == '2') {
              _this.hide();
          }
          return false
      },
      error: function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            _this.html('TEST');
            _this.attr('disabled', false);
        }, 3000);
      }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='load-more-reviews'>TEST</button>
```

Comment: Thank you everybody, I understood it great ! and it works !

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys, I followed your instructions and increased my knownledge.

I am using the Doutriforce's solution with BeforeSend like this :

```
// Loading button
$('button.load-more-reviews').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var _this = $(this);
var product_id = _this.data('product-id');
var limit = _this.data('limit');
var _btn_text = _this.html();
_this.attr('disabled', true);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'actions/ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: 'fetch_reviews',
        product_id: product_id,
        limitcount: limit
    },
   dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
    _this.html('<img src="img/loader/ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Loading...')
    },
    success: function(r) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            _this.html(_btn_text);
            _this.attr('disabled', false);
            console.log(r);
            _this.data('limit', r['limit']);
            if (r['status'] == '1') {
                $('div.reviews-block').append(r['html']);
            } else if (r['status'] == '2') {
                _this.hide();
            }
            return false
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

});

And it works just great !

Many thanks.